# Boa prática passando argumentos para um método quando os mesmos vêm de outra função

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação, parâmetros, groovy

Me deparei com um código parecido com o seguinte:

```
private fazerAlgo(AlgumaCoisa algumaCoisa) {

  Utilidades.converter(
    formatador.formatarParaTal(
      algumaCoisa.a,
      algumaCoisa.b,
      algumaCoisa.c
    )
  )

}
```

À primeira vista eu pensei que o código tava meio bagunçado e complicado assim. É boa prática chamar um método dentro de um argumento para outro método da maneira assim? Ou é melhor extrair o conteúdo dos argumentos para uma variável e usá-la, como por exemplo assim:

```
private fazerAlgo(AlgumaCoisa algumaCoisa) {

  def minhaMensagem = formatador.formatarParaTal(
    algumaCoisa.a,
    algumaCoisa.b,
    algumaCoisa.c
  )

  Utilidades.converter(minhaMensagem)

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Leia o livro chamado: Clean Code(Código Limpo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esqueça esse negócio de boas práticas. Tem que fazer o certo para cada situação. Como não conheço o contexto desta situação não posso falar o que é ideal fazer nela.

Este código todo é esquisito. Se fosse um código real talvez daria para falar melhor.

Eu particularmente não crio variáveis que serão usadas apenas uma vez a não ser que seja um código complexo demais e uma separação ajude a legibilidade, uma variável serve para documentar o código nestes casos.

Tem gente que adora criar um monte de variável para documentar, criar bem mais que uma neste caso. A pessoa acha que explicitar tudo é o mais importante para a legibilidade, espacialmente programadores de Java. De Groovy não deveriam já que é uma linguagem mais puxada para *scripts*. É uma questão de cultura.

Eu gosto de analisar cada caso e ver o que é melhor e pra mim o melhor por padrão é código curto, com poucos *tokens*, até que se mostre necessário ter mais *tokens* para ficar mais legível. Meu código seria assim:

```
private fazerAlgo(AlgumaCoisa algumaCoisa) {
    Utilidades.converter(formatador.formatarParaTal(algumaCoisa.a, algumaCoisa.b, algumaCoisa.c))
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Argument.java).

Principalmente em Groovy. Adoraria que esse `formatarParaTal()` aceitasse o objeto e ele pegasse os elementos, mas não sei se é possível neste "caso".

Então é gosto, é escolha de estilo. De preferência mantenha a consistência. Ou evite variáveis ou sempre use variáveis, até que se prove necessário ser diferente. Escolher um ou outro aleatoriamente não é bom. Se manter a consistência isso por si só já ajuda comunicar a intenção do código.

Se as pessoas pensarem mais sobre a intenção do código e buscarem a simplicidade antes de tudo acabarão tendo mais qualidade e consequentemente mais produtividade no longo prazo.

Comment: e se a linha ficar muito longa e difícil de ler?

Comment: Aí vai do gosto de cada um. Eu não ligo, até pq eu uso line-wrap no editor. Se a pessoa não gostar disto, quebra em uma ou outra linha